# Show that $ \int^1_0 x^3 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x} dx = \frac{\pi}{5!} \frac{1.3.5.7}{2^5} $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I'm trying to show the following.

$$
\int^1_0 x^3 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x} dx = \frac{\pi}{5!} \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7}{2^5}
$$

This is a problem regarding contour integration. My complex analysis knowledge is mostly self taught, so I don't have all the fine details sorted out. From my research on the internet, I think the approach is to construct $f(z)$ so that you it has a branch cut on $[0,1]$ and use branches of the logarithm function. Would appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: You have asked several poorly-composed questions in a short period of time. Rather than asking so many, take your time and write more detailed posts. Your posts do not meet the quality standards that we look for on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this website and did not understand how things worked here. I have tried to edit this post first to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without complex analysis, using a trigonometric substitution. 
Let $x=\sin ^2 \theta $, then $dx = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta$ and you have $$ \int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{1-x} dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} 2 \sin^8 \theta \cos^2 \theta d\theta = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^8 \theta d\theta -2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{10} \theta d\theta $$ If you let $$ I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} sin^n \theta d\theta $$ your answer becomes $2I_8 - 2I_{10}$.

$I_n$ is a well-known general integral. You can solve it by finding a reduction formula by integrating by parts twice and evaluating it directly for $n=0$ and $n=1$.

That should give you the answer. If you need any more details I omitted near the end, tell me.